# Change style and binding in Angular 2

Tags: angular, binding, styles

i am a newbie in Angular 2, so i am studing it and make some prove.

I am trying to create a simple component and make some dynamic issues.

So this is my component:

```
import {Directive, Component, Input, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'textboxcomponent',

    template: require('./textboxparameter.component.html'),
})

export class TextBoxComponent
{
    @Input() labeltext: string;
    @Input() placeholdertext: string;
    @Input() enabletext: boolean;

    //constructor() {
    //    this.enabletext= false;
    //}
}
```

and the associate template:

```
<div class="form-group" >
    <label  for="surname"> {{labeltext}} </label>
    <input class="form-control" id="surname" type="text" required autofocus  
           placeholder={{placeholdertext}} 
           [style.background-color]="enabletext ? 'green': 'red'"/>
</div>
```

So, if I make a value of "enabletext" in the constructor all works fine. Good.

Now i am trying to make a step forward and use the component outside, so created this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'home',
    template: require('./home.component.html')
})
export class HomeComponent { 
}
```

and in its template i am using the previus component:

```
<textboxcomponent labeltext="Surname"  enabletext="false" placeholdertext="placeholder example"></textboxcomponent>
```

So the "placeholder" and "labeltext" works fine, ma not the enabletext, the component is not changing its style whatever value of boolean variable.

What i am missing?

Next step is to create a boolean variable in the homecomponent so i will change the style of textcomponent as i wish in this manner

```
<textboxcomponent labeltext="Surname"  enabletext="homeEnabled" 
placeholdertext="placeholder example"></textboxcomponent>
```

How will i do it?

Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="form-group" >
    <label  for="surname"> {{labeltext}} </label>
    <input class="form-control" id="surname" type="text" required autofocus  
           placeholder={{placeholdertext}} 
           [style.background]="enabletext ? 'green': 'red'"/>
</div>
```

Comment: use `[style.background]` instead

Comment: Thanx for the aswer, but it doesn't work. I think the problem is the binding.

Comment: I solved in this way:
1) I used [style.background-color] in my component
2) when i am using the component in the home component i write:
   [enabletext]="false" 
so all it works.